# Font selection does not look proper

Tags: css, fonts

Im facing an issue while highlighting text. This is normal HTML text. When the text is selected, the selection looks like below image, i.e. the selection looks shifted downward, maybe it starts from the small case character position and does not consider capital letters.

[image]

The font here is "dejavuserif" and the basic CSS attached is,

```
text-align: justify;
line-height: 1.4em;
text-indent: 1em;
font-family: "DejaVuSerif",serif;
font-size: 16px;
```

The highlighted text looks like this,
[image]

Can any one explain why is it so. Is there any way other than changing font to avoid such issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you send an example pls? Fiddle or Homepage

Comment: Once please try to add verticle-align:middle; in your css.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other fonts? Also, are you sure that's the font name? On my computer, there's a font named "DejaVu Serif" with a space, and it doesn't have the problem. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te8Jn.png).

Comment: Yes, that is the font. And I have problem with this font only. I will make a fiddle for same soon.

Comment: @roopa - thanks but that doesn't help

Comment: @trupti Please [show enough code](/help/how-to-ask), ideally as a [mcve]